# Чем заменить метод savedInstanceState?

Tags: java, методы

Пишу следующий код в **Android Studio**:

```
public void onCreate(Button savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

При **запуске эмулятора** выводит такую ошибку:

```
Error:(9, 14) error: no suitable method found for onCreate(Button)
method ActionBarActivity.onCreate(Bundle) is not applicable
(actual argument Button cannot be converted to Bundle by method invocation conversion)
method FragmentActivity.onCreate(Bundle) is not applicable
(actual argument Button cannot be converted to Bundle by method invocation conversion)
method Activity.onCreate(Bundle,PersistableBundle) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Activity.onCreate(Bundle) is not applicable
(actual argument Button cannot be converted to Bundle by method invocation conversion)
```

**Что делать?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перепутали **Bundle** с **Button**.

Замените второе на первое в типе аргумента конструктора и будет вам щастья!

Т.е.:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

вместо

```
public void onCreate(Button savedInstanceState)
```